# Flutter: Alignment of the row's children to the largest element of the row

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried & failed it, but I am still interested in how to solve it:

**Conditions:**

1. You have 1 size-fixed item (200px:200px) and three adaptable items
2. All items placed in the row widget
3. Any item can have a content
4. All adaptable items should fill the available width
5. All adaptable items should adopt the height of the fix-size item or the biggest item in the row automatically.
6. The row widget can be placed in the column widget

My code is:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**My screen result**
[image]

I really cannot understand how to calculate the height, because the maxHeight of the LayoutBuilder returns `double.infinity`, and if use `double.infinity` in the `Container.height` it throws an exception :

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#02e31 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Comment: try `double.maxFinite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the Row with `IntrinsicHeight`. If you like to use `LayoutBuilder`, you can use it on `body`.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, contraints) {
        final width = contraints.maxWidth;
        final height = contraints.maxHeight;

        return Center(
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```